# Joining and Grouping data from 3 tables

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have two tables

Category

```
CategorySerno | CategoryName 
      1            One 
      2            Two
      3            Three
```

Status

```
StatusSerno | Status
1              Active
2              Pending
```

Data

```
CatId |Status |    Date
1       1          2014-07-26 11:30:09.693
2       2          2014-07-25 17:30:09.693
1       1          2014-07-25 17:30:09.693
1       2          2014-07-25 17:30:09.693
```

When I join them I get I need the Joining of the latest Date/
Like

```
One   Active    2014-07-26 11:30:09.693
Two   Inactive  2014-07-25 17:30:09.693
Three  Null      Null
```

When  I am doing a Join and group them It gives me

```
 One   Active    2014-07-26 11:30:09.693
 One   Active    2014-07-26 11:30:09.693
 One   Active    2014-07-26 11:30:09.693
 Two   Inactive  2014-07-25 17:30:09.693
 Three Null       Null
```

Comment: try with `select distinct...` ?

Comment: Please share the sql..

Comment: Show your SQL that gives you the current results you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` in a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT c.CategoryName, 
           s.Status,
           d.Date,
           dateNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CatId, d.Status 
                                        ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM Category c 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Data d
        ON c.CategorySerno = d.CatId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Status s
        ON d.Status = s.StatusSerno 
)
SELECT CategoryName, Status, Date
FROM CTE
WHERE dateNum = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17bd4d/3/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You prabobly have mismatch between SELECT and GROUP BY columns withch couse duplications

Try this:

```
SELECT Category.CategoryName, Status.Status, MAX(Data.Date) Data
FROM Data
LEFT JOIN Category ON Category.CategorySerno = Data.CatId
LEFT JOIN Status ON Status.StatusSerno = Data.Status
GROUP BY Category.CategoryName, Status.Status
```

Comment: I think you need to replace your both *LEFT JOIN* with `RIGHT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the RDBMS you're working in but you might try starting with something like:

```
SELECT
    c.CategoryName
,   s.Status
,   d.Date
FROM
    Data                     d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Category c ON d.CatId  = c.CategorySerno
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Status   s ON d.Status = s.StatusSerno
WHERE
    d.date=(
        SELECT
            max(dd.date)
        FROM
            Data dd
        WHERE
            d.CatId  = dd.CatId
            AND  
            d.Status = dd.Status
    ) z
```

To make this more maintainable in the long run, consider using a convention to identify the primary keys in any table, e.g., table_name_id, and use this same convention for foreign keys. Employing this convention address questions like: is a "CategorySerno" a "CatId"?

Comment: This won't work, because you are comparing `d.date` always to the max-existing datetime of the table *Data*. Not to the maximum datetime of the specific category.

Comment: Looks like you identified a problem with my answer while I was correcting it, @schlonzo. :)

Comment: You are still comparing just to one date for all rows. That means only data with this specific date will be selected. I guess you will usually have a different max-date for every status

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CategoryName, Status.Status, MAX(Data.Date) FROM Category 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data ON CategorySerno = CatId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Status ON Data.Status = Status.StatusSerno 
GROUP BY CategoryName, Status.Status
```